# USB Hub on monitor non-functional

Tags: mac, display, usb, thunderbolt, displayport

I have a late 2012 Mac Mini running Sierra. I have it set up with a Dell U2715h monitor via the thunderbolt port on my Mac, with a miniDP -> DP cable, as the only way to get the full QHD resolution support.

The monitor has several USB ports (USB3 I think) which could be really handy - except they don't work.

I can't find any settings for this on the monitor but as I understand things, the DP/thunderbolt cable should be providing USB connectivity. How can I get this to work?

Comment: You probably need to wire them up separately - they don't work through the video port [or certainly don't as of the 2013 model which are the ones I have]

Comment: As in just connect a USB cable between any 2 ports on the Mac Mini and the monitor?  I guess I'd expected a special "USB in" on the monitor if that was the case, or that the thunderbolt port would be 'magic' somehow :)

Comment: not so much 'any 2 ports' as from an output port to an input port... i.e.  the only one the other end of the cable will fit in. Input ports on mine are underneath, next to the video input. The manual will tell you exactly where.

Comment: Combining your comments solved my problem... if you want to provide an answer I'll accept it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to connect the USB separately, using a standard USB A -> B connector.

[image]

The USB input port on Dell monitors is usually underneath, near the video ports, example below...

[image]

Picture from [Dell - USB Port on Flat Panel Monitor Non-Functional](https://www.dell.com/support/article/us/en/19/sln145032/usb-port-on-flat-panel-monitor-non-functional?lang=en)

Comment: Great. I hadn't realised that weird square port was a USB uplink. All working now :)